# Oracle XE 11g R2 Screen

Tags: oracle, screen, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle11gr2

I have a problem with Oracle SQL Developer.

system info:

- win7 x64
- jdk 7
- oracle xe
- sqldeveloper

I need solve. Problem on the picture.

[image]

Comment: Go to control panel / desktop, and check desktop theme settings (change it to the default "Windows 7").

Comment: sorry i didn't find. can you screen shared?

Comment: Click Start/Control Panel, then check this settings (set them to the default): http://pad2.whstatic.com/images/thumb/5/52/Change-the-Default-Font-on-Windows-7-Step-2.jpg/670px-Change-the-Default-Font-on-Windows-7-Step-2.jpg  Probably some color and font settings were changed and the text is not visible in java dialogs.

Comment: where is it? http://tinypic.com/r/2yxkccg/8

Answer (score 0):

This is that option on my PC, 
so I guess that there is that one on yours --> under the first icon.
[image]